# How to get he Max value after applying multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am seeking for a formula that returns the Max value after applying two criterias.

### I have a table with 3 fields:

Field_A: 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 21, 44, 55, 55, 56, 61, 61, 75, 76, 86

Field_B: 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1

Field_C: 5, 2, 14, 7, 38, 1, 100, 76, 32, 65, 83, 20, 17, 41, 88

### I have two criterias:

Criteria_1: 18, 55, 61, 75, 86  (this is an array)

Criteria_2: 1

### Steps:

Step 1 - Apply Criteria_1 to Field_A

Step 2 - Apply Criteria_2 to Field_B

Step 3 - Return MAX form Field_C after applying step 1 and 2 (Result: 88)

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Is each field a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will return the correct value:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,($C$1:$C$15)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$15,E:E,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$B$15,F:F))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I never used the AGGREGATE function!

Comment: If this worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  @ElioFernandes I am basically doing a MAX(IF()) with the formula.

Comment: Scott, suppose the same problem but with a little difference. How should be the formula if I want the SUM instead of returning the LARGE value?

Comment: Different question = new post